# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi Iam trying to run my hiberanate application i am getting the Hibernate Exception.

my hibernate.cfg.xml file is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">mysql</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <!--   <mapping resource="config\\hibernate.hbm.xml"/ -->
    <mapping resource="config\\employee.hbm.xml"/>>
</session-factory>
```

employee.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

```
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name = "com.javatpoint.mypackage.Employee" table = "emp_TPCH" discriminator-value="emp">
        <id name = "id"> 
            <generator class = "increment">
            </generator>
        </id>
        <discriminator column="type" type= "string"></discriminator>
        <property name ="Name"></property>

        <subclass name = "com.javatpoint.mypackage.Regular_Employee" discriminator-value="reg_emp">
        <property name = "salary"></property>
        <property name = "bonus"></property>
        </subclass>

        <subclass name = "com.javatpoint.mypackage.Contract_Employee" discriminator-value = "con_emp">
        <property name = "pay_Per_Hour"></property>
        <property name = "contact_Duration"></property>
        </subclass>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Employee.java is

```
package com.javatpoint.mpackage;
```

public class Employee {

```
private int id;
private String name;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getname() {
    return name;
}
public void setname(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Contract_Employee.java

package com.javatpoint.mpackage;

public class Contract_Employee extends Employee {

```
private float pay_Per_Hour;
private String contact_Duration;

public float getPay_Per_Hour() {
    return pay_Per_Hour;
}
public void setPay_Per_Hour(float pay_Per_Hour) {
    this.pay_Per_Hour = pay_Per_Hour;
}
public String getContact_Duration() {
    return contact_Duration;
}
public void setContact_Duration(String contact_Duration) {
    this.contact_Duration = contact_Duration;
}
```

}

Regular Employee.js is

```
package com.javatpoint.mpackage;
```

public class Regular_Employee extends Employee {

```
private float salary;
private int bonus;

public float getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(float salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
public int getBonus() {
    return bonus;
}
public void setBonus(int bonus) {
    this.bonus = bonus;
}
```

}

Guys please help me to come out of this Exception.

Comment: And the stack trace of the exception is?

Answer (score 2):

Include this as the second line in your file:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are maybe other errors, but this line is invalid:

```
<mapping resource="config\\employee.hbm.xml"/>>
                                              ^-- two brackets here
```

Also, the resource should be `config/employee.hbm.xml`. The resource is a classpath resource, using forward slashes as path separator.

Comment: While changing resourse to "config/employee.hbm.xml"> Still it is showing  Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource config/employee.hbm.xml

Comment: And the full stack trace of the exception is?